# HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback firing very prematurely

Tags: stm32, hal

I am using STM32CubeIDE with an STM32G030 micro. I attempted to implement a simple interrupt-based timeout timer on Timer17 using the HAL driver. See attached file “Screenshot1”for the TIM7configuration info.

[image]

Here’s the Init Code generated from the setup in the .ioc file:

```
/* USER CODE END TIM17_Init 1 */
htim17.Instance = TIM17;
htim17.Init.Prescaler = 64 - 1;
htim17.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim17.Init.Period = 10000 - 1;
htim17.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
htim17.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
htim17.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim17) != HAL_OK)
{
    Error_Handler();
}
```

My micro is running a 64 MHz clock, so the prescaler setting has it running at 1 MHz (counting microseconds). I ran the htim17.Init.Period in the .ioc out to 65536 - 1 to handle a 50 millisecond interval and tested to see if it was running correctly with this simple, no-interrupt code from [Sean Hymel’s Digi-Key instructional video](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/getting-started-with-stm32-timers-and-timer-interrupts/d08e6493cefa486fb1e79c43c0b08cc6).

```
while (1)
{
/*TEMP TIMER TEST*/
timer_val = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim17);

HAL_Delay(50);

timer_val = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim17) - timer_val;
sprintf(data_buffer,”%u us\r\n”, timer_val);
Send_UART_NonBlocking();

HAL_Delay(1000);
/*END TEMP TEST */

}
```

That achieves the same terminal output as Sean’s result in the video - 51000 microseconds each time (he was unable to explain why the timer always measures 1 msec more than we expected. So I know the timer is being clocked correctly at an internal 1 microsecond - per - count rate.

The malfunction comes when I tried to set up the

```
HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback
```

interrupt. I start it with this instruction:

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim17);
```

In the Callback function, I am checking to make sure the source of the interrupt is Timer17. Here is my ISR:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim == &htim17) //make the interrupt triggered off of our intended timer
    {
        HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim17); //reset and de-allocate the timer
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DIAG_PA12_GPIO_Port, DIAG_PA12_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        TimeOutFlag_17 = true; //flag indicates to other functions that we triggered this timeout
    }
}
```

I have a diagnostic port going high upon calling

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT,
```

and I am driving it low in the ISR - the

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(DIAG_PA12_GPIO_Port, DIAG_PA12_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

statement above. I am measuring only 5.83 microseconds from the Start function call to the logic low write instruction in the Callback ISR! If I break on the HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT function call, and single - step through the code, the interrupt fires within one statement after returning from that function. Looking at the timer’s CNT register in the IDE’s SFRs tab, CNT is jumping erratically from one executed C instruction to the next while single - stepping. Yet when NOT using the interrupt code, the timer runs accurately. I am stumped. What am I doing wrong with this simple interrupt implementation?

Comment: When you single step through the code, the CNT registers show random values, because the timers continue to run in the background, even when the code hits a breaktpoint. So the timers are free-running and each time you single-step, the value from that exact moment is read.

Comment: Btw. the first code snipped always returns 51ms, because the HAL_Delay is adding one ms to the function parameter, to make sure that the funtion really delays by at least on ms. Because systick resolution is only 1ms, it could happen that the delay function already returns after a single clock cycle, if by chance the systick interrupt happend immediately after the function call. So it was the decision of ST to make the delay rather 1ms to long than 1ms to short.

Comment: Could you please check where the HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback is called? It might be a more generic interrupt that can also be fired from other sources?

Comment: Thank you, jusaca for pointing out that the breakpoint doesn't stop the timer, and explaining what I observed.

Comment: The callback function is being called from line 3976 of my stock (unmodified) stm32g0x_hal_time.c.. Single - stepping through all of the HAL_TIM_IRQHandler() code beginning at the top of that function at line 3845, I don't see any evidence of the triggering source being anything other than a TIM update event beginning at line 3967. What else should I look for?

Answer (score 3):

You don't show the full code, but my guess is, you set and enable the callback after the timer has already elapsed once or many times, so there is a pending elapsed event which triggers immediately when you try to enable the functionality. It may be due to you using debugger and the timer runs even if code is stopped. It may be that you enable the callback after timer has alredy been running due to spending time running any other code before enabling the callback.

And why the HAL seems to wait one extra millisecod; it can be simply explained by looking at the source code of HAL_Delay - surprised that your source of information did not bother to check it and left it as mystery.

First of all, the HAL code adds 1 timer tick, and as they happen at 1ms in your system, asking for a 50ms delay will guarantee you get a delay of 51 ticks of the timer that increases the time variable.

The comment also explains why it adds the 1 timer tick. As when you call the HAL_Delay with some parameter like 50, you likely call it at a random time compared to the system timer ticks. So there can be a time range between 0 and 1 milliseconds before the next tick happens. If you want a 50ms delay, the HAL is guaranteed to give you a 50ms delay, in the range of 50 to 51 milliseconds, by adding one more tick to wait. If it did not do this, then you would be asking why you get time delays between 49 and 50 milliseconds even if you asked for 50 because you thought it will be enough and you get exactly 50ms but no less. It is hard to please everyone and with 1ms timer ticks, you only get 1ms precision or granularity in the times you need to delay.

Comment: "my guess is, you set and enable the callback after the timer has already elapsed once or many times."

Hmmm, yes that would fit the symptoms! I don't have much code associated with the timer at all. There is the init code toward the top of my post, and this HALL call that I thought was all I needed to start the timer:

HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim17);

As I said, in HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(); I am verifying that the source of the interrupt is Timer17, but nothing beyond that.
1. Do you see an other potential timer start points?
2. If so, how would I chase them in the IDE?

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the extra millisecond since Sean Hymel didnt. :-)

Comment: After posting my first comment, I went a bit further.
I ran to a breakpoint on my HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT() call, after which, the malfunction happens immediately. The timer is definitely not running because:
a. TIM17 control register 1, bit 0 CEN (Counter Enable) is reset.
b. TIM17 CNT register is 0 at that breakpoint.

So I see no chance that that I have "set and enable the callback after the timer has already elapsed once or many times, so there is a pending elapsed event which triggers immediately when you try to enable the functionality." Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of gurus at community.st.com answered this for me.
["Cube/HAL functions generate an Update during setup, so the UIF flag is already set.](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubeide-mcus/hal-tim-periodelapsedcallback-firing-very-prematurely/m-p/588486)"

I had to reset the UIF flag before calling `HAL_TIM_Base_Start()`.

```
    TIM17->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim17); //start 30 msec timeout timer
```

while waiting for MM to assert our NSS pin

I don't know why STM didn't reset the flag as the first instruction in `HAL_TIM_Base_Start()`, but there it is.

Comment: "update" is what latches new values into a bunch of the configuration registers.  Perhaps you would be better off coding your periodic actions to trigger from the event producing the update, and not from the update itself (which as you see can also be produced from software).